# How can I iterate the DAO fields collection with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dao, hta

I wrote an HTML Application that worked pretty well. These are files ending with .hta that open only with internet explorer. In the app I was using an object with property names as key values for a database. Since this is windows and Microsoft I decided to convert to DAO. Over the years I've done much work with DAO, but always with VB, VBA, or .net syntax, not Javascript.

With Javascript, if I name the fields in a recordset as properties of the recordset object, i.e. with a period, they are accessible, but then I have to hard code this way and it isn't dynamic. What I want to do is iterate through the Fields collection of the recordset object and obtain field names. I'm unable to get this to work. It keeps saying "cannot get Name from a null instance of an object".

In the db_update function below I am passing an object having property names matching field names in the recordset. The routine is flexible and allows me to avoid hard coding field names. I was doing that, but want to change to this format, and it won't work. I can't find any info anywhere using DAO with Javascript. A note in the routine says "IT FAILS ON THIS LINE". The Count property is present in the Fields collection with the correct value, so there is a Fields collection.

```js
function setup() {
  db_engine = new ActiveXObject("DAO.DBEngine.36");
  fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
.....
  if (fso.FileExists(mdb)) fso.DeleteFile(mdb);
  db_db = db_engine.CreateDatabase(mdb,";LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0");
  var table = db_db.CreateTableDef("file"), ord=1;
  db_create_field(table,"id",4,4,ord,false,false);
  ord++;
  db_create_field(table,"path",10,255,ord,false,false);
  ord++;
  db_create_field(table,"local",3,2,ord,false,false);
  ord++;
.....
}
function db_create_field(table,name,type,length,ordinal,required,allow_zl) {
  var fld = table.CreateField(name,type,length);
  fld.Attributes = 1;
  fld.OrdinalPosition = ordinal;
  fld.ValidationRule = "";
  fld.ValidationText = "";
  fld.Required = required ? -1 : 0;
  try {
    fld.AllowZeroLength = allow_zl ? -1 : 0;
  }
  catch(e) {
  }
  table.Fields.Append(fld);
}
function db_update(wad) {
  var rst=db_db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM file WHERE path='"+wad.path+"'",2);
  if (rst.EOF) {
    rst.AddNew();
    rst.id = file_id++;
    rst.path = wad.path;
  }
  else {
    rst.edit();
  }
  var count=rst.Fields.Count, name;
  for (var j=0;j<count;j++) {
    name = rst.Fields[j].Name;  // IT FAILS ON THIS LINE FOR "NAME"
    if (wad.hasOwnProperty(name)) rst.Fields[j] = wad[name];
  }
  rst.Update();
  rst.Close();
}
```

Comment: Maybe I have to instantiate an enumerator object. This is what's required to iterate the files and folders collections of the file system object. Maybe the same applies here, too. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW SOLUTION

This is my final solution which works faster. The search field is placed outside the wad so not to update unnecessarily, and no enumeration needed. If a property is in the wad that isn't in the recordset field list, an error will of course be generated.

```js
function db_update(path,wad) {
  var rst=db_db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM file WHERE path='"+path+"'",2);
  if (rst.EOF) {
    rst.AddNew();
    rst.id = file_id++;
    rst.path = path;
  }
  else {
    rst.edit();
  }
  var keys = object_keys(wad);
  for (var j=0;j<keys.length;j++) rst[keys[j]] = wad[keys[j]];
  rst.Update();
  rst.Close();
}
function object_keys(obj) {
  var keys = [], j = 0;
  for (keys[j++] in obj) {};
  return keys;
}
```

Previous answer:

Yes, enumeration worked. I changed the db_update routine as follows. I wish I'd thought of enumeration before posting. Maybe this will help someone else.

```js
function db_update(wad) {
  var rst=db_db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM file WHERE path='"+wad.path+"'",2);
  if (rst.EOF) {
    rst.AddNew();
    rst.id = file_id++;
    rst.path = wad.path;
  }
  else {
    rst.edit();
  }
  var en = new Enumerator(rst.Fields), name;
  for (;!en.atEnd();en.moveNext()) {
    name = en.item().Name;
    if (wad.hasOwnProperty(name)) en.item().Value = wad[name];
  }
  rst.Update();
  rst.Close();
}
```